# What is better practice of writting code in laravel 5.*

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
DB::beginTransaction();
    try{
        $product = Product::create($request->all());
        DB::commit();
        return [
            'product' => $product
        ];
    }catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        DB::rollBack();
        throw new ResourceException($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Is it needed to start transaction, that return product if all ok or rollback if problem? Or this code will be enough:

```
$product = Product::create($request->all());
        return [
        'product' => $product
    ];
```

Comment: by return a product u mean by select?

Comment: Yes its good to use this code,but `beginTransaction` is used generally for two or more query to commit or rollback

Comment: single query, there is no need for transaction

Comment: @oleh you don't need them in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tranasaction is only required when you have a set of queries that must be executed altogether.

For example - If in a bank, if A transfers money to B, then both the accounts will be changed, A's account will be deducted with the amount, where as there will be addition in B's account. So, if any of the task fails there will be problem with the system.

So, we use transactions in such cases. The set of queries meant to be executed together are kept as a transaction. If any query fails, the other query will be rolled back.

You can read more on internet.

So, if you are executing a single query, there is no need for transaction. Second approach will do just fine.